# Explain the Use of "Zachur Latov"

Tags: language, eliyahu-hanavi

Frequently, when we refer to Eliyahu (Elijah the prophet), the term זכור לטוב ("Remembered for good things") is used. I vaguely recall seeing the Talmud use this term for someone else, but I don't recall whom.

What is the reason fro using this term for Eliyahu or certain other people? What merits someone to have this term used? Is it reserved just for dead people, or can this be said about a meritorious living person?

Comment: Charvona from Megila is referred to as Zachur Latov in the after-blessings on the Megila. וְגַם חַרְבוֹנָה זָכוּר לַטּוֹב

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zachur letov is used only when referring to people that have never died, but aren't easily accessible among the living. Examples of such are Eliyahu Hanavi (who went to heaven without dying), Charvona (actually Eliyahu Hanavi in the guise of a Persian soldier in Achashverosh's army; https://www.ou.org/holidays/purim/shoshanat_yaakov/), Rabi Yehoshua Ben-Levi, Eliezer Eved Avraham, and seven others who never died and entered gan eden alive (see Derech Eretz Zuta 1).

Comment: Chacham Nisan thank you very much for your recent contributions. Great to have you with us. I see others already commented on the fact that non-sourced answers are generally not well received here, and I'm sure you will gradually start providing sources to back up your statements. Also, the minhag on the site is not to include a starting welcome (Shalom u'vracha!) nor an ending one. I allowed myself slight edits to your post, you can always reverse them by clicking edit below your post. Welcome again!

Comment: How do you know this? Do we ever see Eliezer Eved Avraham called Zakhur Latov? You found one thing in common between Eliyahu and one opinion of who Charvonah was, but couldn't there be other possible patterns?

Comment: @DoubleAA There could; please show them to me. Have you seen ztz"l appended to Eliezer Eved Avraham or any of the others? If so, it's a mistake; because I've seen it appended to Eliyahu Hanavi and we know it's not true.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen a couple of sefarim bring down from a commentary called "Mekor Chesed" to Sefer Chasidim that "zachur latov" is based on the pasuk in I Kings 17:18, where the woman feared that Eliyahu was coming to cause her to be remembered for the bad, that her sins would be recalled. We therefore pray that when Eliyahu comes it should be for the good and that we should be remembered for the good. [image: quote from "Mekor Chesed" to Sefer Chasidim]